# Perform search using HQL/which join type to user?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

I have the following model;

- I have users and rules
- a user can be added to 0, 1 or more rules
- a rule can contain 0, 1 or more users

Here is the UserEntity class:

```
    class UserEntity {

    private String username;

    private List<RuleEntity> rules;

    @Column(name = "username", nullable = false, unique = true)
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="users" , fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public List<RuleEntity> getRules() {
        return rules;
    }

    ...
}
```

And the RuleEntity class:

```
    class RuleEntity {
        private String name;

        private List<UserEntity> users;

        @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
        public String getRuleName() {
             return ruleName;
        }

        @ManyToMany (fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinTable(name= "RULE_USER" ,joinColumns=@JoinColumn
        (name=RuleEntity.RULE_ID, referencedColumnName="ID", insertable = true, updatable = false, nullable = false),
      inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn
      (name=UserEntity.USER_ID, referencedColumnName="ID", insertable = true, updatable = false, nullable = false), 
      uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {RuleEntity.RULE_ID, UserEntity.USER_ID}))
      public List<UserEntity> getUsers() {
         return users;
      }

      ...
  }
```

I am trying to implement a search whereby a user can search using:

- only a username
- only a rulename
- a username and a rulename

So I am performing 2 HQL queries, one to return the matching users and one to return the matching rules e.g.

```
public SearchResults search(String maybePartialUsername, String maybePartialRuleName) {
    List<UserEntity> userEntities = hqlQuery("select distinct users from UserEntity as users inner join users.rules as rules where users.username like :maybePartialUsername and rules.ruleName like :maybePartialRuleName");

    List<RuleEntity> ruleEntities = hqlQuery("select distinct rules from RuleEntity as rules inner join rules.users as users where users.username like :maybePartialUsername and rules.ruleName like :maybePartialRuleName");

    return SearchResults(userEntities, ruleEntities);
}
```

The first HQL query for finding users matching a username (and/or rulename) works fine when a user is a member of at least one rule, but it returns no results when a user has not been added to any rules.

Changing the 'inner join' to a 'left join' does not help. The problem lies in the 'rules.ruleName like :maybePartialRuleName' condition, if I remove this the query works, but I need this in the query in the cases where the join with the rules tables succeeds (i.e. a user DOES have rules), and thus I then need to filter by rule name as well as username.

```
select distinct users from UserEntity as users inner join users.rules as rules where users.username like :maybePartialUsername and rules.ruleName like :maybePartialRuleName
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me (thanks @sergiu):

The following method creates the select part of the query:

```
public List<UserEntity> search(final String maybePartialUsername, final String maybePartialRuleName)
      throws EntityException {
    final String selectUsersStatement = "select distinct users from UserEntity as users";
    final String joinUsersWithRulesClause = shouldFilterSearchBy(maybePartialRuleName) ? "inner join users.rules as rules" : null;


    return search(Joiner.on(" ").skipNulls().join(selectUsersStatement, joinUsersWithRulesClause),
        maybePartialUsername, maybePartialRuleName);
  }
```

Which then calls a method (not shown) which calls the following to build the where parts of the query:

```
private String buildSearchQueryFrom(final String selectStatement, final String maybePartialUsername,
      final String maybePartialRuleName) {
    final Collection<String> searchFilters = Lists.newArrayListWithCapacity(2);

    if (shouldFilterSearchBy(maybePartialUsername)) {
      searchFilters.add("users.username like :maybePartialUsername");
    }

    if (shouldFilterSearchBy(maybePartialRuleName)) {
      searchFilters.add("rules.ruleName like :maybePartialRuleName");
    }

    final String whereClauseParts = Joiner.on(" and ").skipNulls().join(searchFilters);
    return Joiner.on(" where ").skipNulls().join(selectStatement, whereClauseParts);
  }
```

And a helper method called by the method above:

```
protected boolean shouldFilterSearchBy(final String searchValue) {
        return !Strings.isNullOrEmpty(searchValue);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try left join

select distinct users from UserEntity as users left join users.rules as rules where users.username like :maybePartialUsername and rules.ruleName like :maybePartialRuleName.

It will give you all that's int left side (userEntity in this case).

Comment: thanks, though left join doesn't work either, its returning zero results as with inner join, the problem with this is that with a left/inner join, this section of sql 'rules.ruleName like :maybePartialRuleName' causes the result to return zero results.

Comment: Is there a record that matches both conditions?

Comment: No, in this scenario a user has no rules.

Comment: Ok, so you need to pass the conditions only when they are not null or empty. For example if maybePartialRuleName is null or empty the query will not contain "and rules.ruleName like :maybePartialRuleName". The same applies for the other condition. Inner join must be used.

Comment: Thanks @sergiu, I've updated this post with my answer based on your comments.

Comment: I have a related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22504703/why-is-this-hql-search-query-not-working if you'd be kind enough to have a look at it @sergiu thanks!